# error from gs when given the input as $(ls -v)

Tags: ghostscript

I have a long list of pdf files which I am trying to merge in a single file. If I give the command

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/default -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -dDetectDuplicateImages -dCompressFonts=true -r150 -sOutputFile=blender_manual.pdf $(ls -v)
```

gs exits with the error

```
    Error: /undefinedfilename in (1.1)
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1173/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:77/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory
GPL Ghostscript 9.06: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

The command works if I put *.pdf instead of $(ls -v) but in this case it merges the files in the wrong order. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the @file syntax (see the Ghostscript documentation), list the files you want processed, in the order you want them processed.